# School manages Google accounts, what can they do or see?

Tags: google, gmail

My school started using Google Meet for online classes. The accounts we use are managed by them and they told us that they know the IP of the device that we are logging in from. What else can they know/monitor?

Can they see our search history? Our files at Drive, our documents at Google Docs? Do they only see your activity if you use that account?

I kind of got anxious, because they will somehow know if we are cheating. And no, I won't attempt cheating because I actually want to learn. I'm a bit paranoid, can they also see activity on other browsers or other Google accounts? How do managed Google accounts work?

Comment: Is your school using G Suite or do you have a private Gmail account?

Comment: According to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65769/can-the-employer-view-my-google-youtube-history-on-google-apps-platform) question the only way they'd be able to do that is if they changed your password, but it's from years ago so I don't know if it still applies.

Comment: Google's support may answer some of these questions, I'd imagine, but generally I'd assume they can see everything related to your school account and nothing more unless granted otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Provided it's a G-Suite account (and it almost certainly is, as this is the *only* way they can manage the accounts unless you gave them your login credentials), they can see all data associated with that account, including but not limited to emails, search history, Youtube watch history, and numerous other things (for example, browsing history if you've logged into Google Chrome with this account as your primary account).

However, unless you explicitly grant access, they do not have any access to data on your other Google accounts (with the possible exception of the fact that you have logged in with other Google Accounts on the same device, but probably not what accounts those are).